# Wireless works only after reboot after disabling it via hardware keys

Tags: wireless, laptop

I have an Asus Eee 1005 HA-H which can disable the wireless on some hardware level with FN+F2. If I reenable it, the Gnome network manager tells me that this device is not ready to use. Once I reboot, it is back online.

How could I reenable it while the computer is still on? I'd like to disable it on the fly to save battery power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

Suggestion 1 - stop and start the network manager service

```
sudo initctl restart network-manager
```

Suggestion 2 - unload and reload the wireless kernel module

Find the wireless module via

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

Look for `driver=` in the configuration line - the kernel name is after that

for example for my wireless:

`configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38`

```
sudo modprobe -r wl0
sudo modprobe wl0
```

N.B. you could use Suggestion 1 after this to force network manager to recognise the change in the kernel.

Comment: Interestingly, it just works out of the box now, I can enable and disable wireless lan on the fly. I'll keep your suggestions around if it will not work any more.

Comment: ... maybe speculative - possibly a recent kernel update added a fix?

Comment: It could be. It must have happened within the last couple weeks. There was a new kernel IIRC.